# How to stop a loop in powershell

Tags: powershell

This script is supposed to create a file or files and if there is more  than 1 put 1 after name then 2 then 3 and so on.. and if its  0 or less to say: You must select at least one file to be created

````
$Filename=Read-Host "Enter desired filename"
$NewFilePath=Read-Host "Enter desired path"
$AmtOfFiles=Read-Host "Enter desired amount of files"

if($AmtOfFiles -ge 1){
for($AmtOfFiles=1;$AmtOfFiles -gt 0){
New-Item -ItemType file -Path $NewFilePath -Name $Filename$i
$i++
}
}
else{Write-Output "You must select at least one file to be created.”}```
````

Comment: please Read The Friendly Manual - specifically look at `Get-Help about_For`. the examples make your "endless loop" problem quite clear. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get help on the for command from PowerShell by typing:

```
get-help about_for
```

You can also see [this Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-7) for the same info.

The for command has 3 parameters in the parens, not the two you are using in your example.

```
for (<init>; <condition>; <repeat>) 
{<statement list>}
```

You need to use a control variable, like $i, in the definition of the For.  So modifying your code, it would look like this:

```
If($AmtOfFiles -ge 1){
    for($i=1;$i -lt $AmtOfFiles;$i++)
    {
        New-Item -ItemType file -Path $NewFilePath -Name $Filename$i
    }
}
else{
    Write-Output "You must select at least one file to be created.”
}
```

Please read the documentation for more info on how to use for loops properly.  You'll be happy you did.

Hope this helps.

Comment: appreciate it and will do right now, just always forgetting basic stuff that i should know! i get that i  was missing the condition

Comment: @DavidBrand Have you seen these last two comments?